# Corrupt c-style string input, where does it go wrong? (C++)

Tags: c++, list, struct, c-strings

Well, I've been stuck on this bug I keep getting. When I run the Phonebook project and add a few contacts, some strings (converted to char-arrays for the database) end up corrupt, which prints a smiley face, as I've gathered. I can't really grasp where it's coming from. I might just be missing the obvious, but I'd appreciate it if you take a look.

Pastebin.com link: [SOURCE CODE](http://pastebin.com/3cFtYVGJ)

Comment: This should probably be on code reviews SE.

Comment: You're not null-terminating your strings when you copy them.

Comment: Are the entries corrupted in the text file? or just when read back in?

Comment: You should narrow down your problem, post code that conforms to [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  Asking us to parse through your entire program to figure out the problem is off topic for all Stack Exchange forums.

Comment: Can you post an example of the input you give to the program so that I can improve my answer please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very large program, so forgive me if I haven't pointed out everything. But this is one thing that I've come across that I see as potentially dangerous, or that might have something to do with your primary issue:

You're mixing formatted input with unformatted input without taking the proper precautions. Unformatted input functions (unlike its formatted variants) do not discard new lines from the stream. By default, when performing formatted I/O (say with `operator>>`), the extraction halts at the discovery of a whitespace character. This character is left in the stream until the next operation where it is either discarded or extracted into a datum adequate for its type.

Before I go on, I'll show you the code pertaining to this situation:

> ```
> ifile >> b[a].id;
> getline(ifile, temp);
> ```

`std::getline()` will access `infile` and look at the next character available in its buffer. If the next character is equal to a new line character or a specified delimiter, that character is not extracted. Instead the function will discard that character and return.

The effect is that `temp` is not given a value and there is still more data left in the stream that is unexpected.

Solution: Discarding the leading whitespace. Also, **always** check if your I/O succeeded. A simple if statement should do:

> ```
> if (std::getline(infile >> b[a].id >> std::ws, temp)) {
>     //                                ^^^^^^^
> }
> ```

You have a lot of these in your program so check wherever you're using unformatted I/O following an formatted extraction and do the relevant changes. You should also consider using `std::string` where ever possible.

<sub>Note that you can also improve your program by implementing a custom inserter for your `derp` class.</sub>